# When I delete roles that contains duplicate value in other work sheets using VBA,How come the roles that does not contain duplicates are also removed

Tags: vba, excel

I want to remove any rows in which IDs in Column B have already appeared in the "Trade" sheet. But when I delete the rows using the following code, the rows of IDs that are not duplicates are also deleted (with the bizarre exception of the topmost one). Is my deletion code incorrect?

Here is my code:

```
Sub Removeduplicate()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim num As Integer
Dim lastCellB As Range
    num = 0
    For i = 2 To 10000
        If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Manual").Cells(i, 2).Value > 0 Then
          num = num + 1
         End If
    Next i
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Manual").Range("B5000").Select
    j = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Manual").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Do While num > 0
      lastvalue = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Manual").Cells(j, 2).Value
      For i = 2 To 10000
        If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Trade").Cells(i, 4).Value = lastvalue Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Manual").Cells(j, 2).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
      Next i
      j = j - 1
      num = num - 1
     Loop
MsgBox ("Removed")


End Sub
```

Here are screenshots of my data "Trade" sheet

[image: "Trade" sheet]

and "Manual" sheet

[image: "Manual" sheet].

Comment: There is no image of the sheet "manual" which is the one mostly used. Plus did you try pressing F8, evaluating the step one by one and then find out the issue?

Comment: you need to get rid of the `select` statements ... use fully qualified references to worksheet cells ... both of your `if` statement contain the correct format, but the rest of the code does not, for some reason. why is your programming style so inconsistent?  ... once you do that, then your code should be simpler, and easier to debug   .... your first two `select` statements do not do anything useful

Comment: Jsotola: I've reuploaded the codes eliminating the select function.But the issue is still not solved .

Comment: I think the problem might appear in the delete code" ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Manual").Cells(j, 2).EntireRow.Delete". It somehow also deleted the line below instead of just the current line. I tried other codes it works well. But I did not how where went wrong with this delete function.

Comment: Tested code and works fine for me too, it's a little slow but it works

Comment: Maldred: Does your result with the non-duplicate ones (except the top one) remained?  Mine still not working and I also tried another way to delete the rows: ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Manual").Rows(j).Delete

Comment: comment out `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Manual").Cells(j, 2).EntireRow.Delete` .... then add just below the commented out line the following ... `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Manual").Cells(j, 2).EntireRow.select` then add `stop` below that .... that will cause the program to pause .... and the line that would have been deleted will be selected  ... just check the worksheet to see which line is selected

Comment: what is the purpose of the first `for` loop ?

Comment: the purpose of first for loop is to find the number of ISIN in "manual" sheet

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Removeduplicate()

With activeworkbook

Dim TradeSheet as worksheet
Set TradeSheet = activeworkbook.worksheets("Trade")

Dim IDsOnTradeSheet as variant
IDsOnTradeSheet = application.transpose(tradesheet.range("D2:D10000").value2)

Dim IDsOnManualSheet as variant
IDsOnManualSheet = application.transpose(.worksheets("Manual").range("B2:B10000").value2)

End with

' Loop through each Manual Sheet ID and keep trying to find each one in Trade Sheet IDs.'

Dim ReadIndex as long
Const TRADEIDCOLUMN as string = "B"
Dim Counter as long

Dim MatchResult as variant 'This variable will contain either number or error.'

Dim RowsToDelete() as string
Redim RowsToDelete(1 to 10000)

For readindex = lbound(idsonmanualsheet) to ubound(Idsonmanualsheet)

Do
Matchresult = application.match(idsonmanualsheet(readindex),idsontradesheet,0)
If isnumeric(matchresult) then
Counter = counter + 1
RowsToDelete(Counter) = tradeidcolumn & (matchresult+1) '+1= offset, as first row = 2 and lbound should = 1)'
End if
Doevents
Loop until iserror(matchresult)

Next readindex

Redim preserve RowsToDelete(lbound(RowsToDelete) to counter)

With Application
.screenupdating = false
.calculation = xlcalculationmanual

Tradesheet.range(strings.join(RowsToDelete,",").entirerow.delete

.screenupdating = true
.calculation = xlcalculationautomatic
End With

MsgBox ("Removed")
End Sub
```

1. Does it work?
2. Does it do what you want?

Written on mobile, sorry for bad formatting/indentation.

Comment: Thanks for the coding but this has an error for the delete line. However I found the reason why mine does not work. It is besause the for loop just continues after the duplicate line is deleted . And add a simple line of i=10000 after delete.entirerow works. but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my comments hope you'll find it useful:

1. In deleting rows using `For...Next` loop, `Step -1` should be used

   ```
   'Example
   For i = 10000 to 2 Step -1
       ...
   Next`
   ```

   Why? Well lets say `i` is now at `i = 3` and this entire row is deleted. After deleting, row #4 now becomes row #3. So, on `Next`, `i` will iterate to `i = 4`, but now it will be checking on row #5 because your entire table has been shifted upward begin from row #4 because row #3 was deleted.
2. Use builtin `Worksheetfunction` when possible instead of custom making them, because it will perform much much faster than custom made function (or procedure).

   ```
   'You can replace this:
   num = 0
   For i = 2 To 10000
       If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Manual").Cells(i, 2).Value > 0 Then
         num = num + 1
        End If
   Next i

   'with this
   num = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Manual").Range("B:B")) - 1
   ```
3. No need to `.Select` anything to use with `.End(xlUp)`. `Select` is used for visual only.

   ```
    'This line can be deleted.
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Manual").Range("B5000").Select
   ```
4. Again, using `Worksheetfunction`, to find whether the ISIN in "Manual" exist in "Trade" sheet, you can do something like this

   ```
   If Application.Worksheetfunction.CountIf(Sheets("Trade").Range("D:D"), _
       Sheets("Manual").Cells(i, "B") ) > 0 Then

       Sheets("Manual").Cells(i, "B").EntireRow.Delete
   End If
   ```
5. If you are running this macro on one workbook only i.e. ActiveWorkbook, then you can omit qualifying your references to `ActiveWorkbook`. However because you are running this macro across two sheets i.e. "Manual" and "Trade", then you should qualify all your references to the respective worksheet.

In short, what i see is you only need to do one time of `For...Next` loop to remove the unwanted rows. There is no need for the `Do While...Loop` loop.

R

Comment: thanks . This works way much better than mine . But I am still wondering even though my code is slow, it should be correct . I replaced the first loop to find num with yours and remains  And I think your No.1 comment is great but might misunderstand the cell I deleted is "manual" cell(j,2) not the cell(i,4)  I compared with in "trade" . So delete row should not affect the loop.

Comment: @SusanLiu will there be duplicate ISIN in the "Trade" sheet itself? If yes, you have to use `Exit For` to terminate `for...loop` for `i` once the row has been deleted so that it won't delete more than once on "Manual" sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Using Union method is easy and fast.

```
Sub Removeduplicate()
    Dim rngU As Range, rng As Range
    Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, bWs As Worksheet
    Dim Wf As WorksheetFunction

    Set Wf = WorksheetFunction

    Set Ws = Sheets("Manual")
    Set bWs = Sheets("Trade")

    With bWs
        Set rngB = .Range("d2", .Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    With Ws
        Set rngA = .Range("b2", .Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each rng In rngA
        If Wf.CountIf(rngB, rng) Then
            If rngU Is Nothing Then
                Set rngU = rng
            Else
                Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
            End If
        End If
    Next rng
    If Not rngU Is Nothing Then
        rngU.EntireRow.Delete
        MsgBox "Removed"
    End If
End Sub
```